# Slide menu not showing on the view controller which is presented on another view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, side-menu

I am using the Side menu controller. The Side view controller works fine but when another view controller B is presented over another view controller A. The side menu doesnot appears on the view controller B while swiping. The code for embedding the side menu controller is:

```
let homeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeLandingIdentifier") as? HomeLandingViewController
  let leftViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "SideBar", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sideBar") as? SideBarViewController
  let mainNavigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController!)
  let slideMenuController = SlideMenuTrackerController(mainViewController: mainNavigationController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController!)
  AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
  leftViewController?.mainViewController = mainNavigationController
  slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
  AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
  AppDelegate.sharedInstance().window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

The code for presenting the view controller is:

```
let viewcontroller = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeSearchIndentifier") as? HomeSearchViewController
let searchViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchRideIdentifier") as? SearchRideViewController
searchViewController?.parentView = .homeLandingPage
let duration = 0.4
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = duration
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
self.navigationController!.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewcontroller!, animated: false)
viewcontroller?.present(searchViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

The side menu which i am using is:

[Side menu](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

Comment: While this doesn't "fix" your code, I prefer to use someone's code that solved all of this and save me development time.  The CocoaPods "SidebarOverlay" works wonders and solve this for me.

Comment: @ekscrypto does it works on the presented view controller?

Comment: Yes, works for me.  I believe the "trick" they've done is have a small UIView with a gesture recognizer be permanently on top where the menu should appear so when you "drag" from the edge of the screen your finger is on top of that view.  They can then drag the view and the menu along with your gesture to reveal the menu.  This means that you need a root container view to be always below that view.  You instantiate and add your navigation controller to that root view.  This magic is all done by SidebarOverlay or many other similar libraries